# dll no se carga en php wamp

Tags: php

Tengo una dll que necesito agregar y utilizar en php corriendo en WAMP.

Agregué la dll en la carpeta ext y en el php.ini agregué extension=mi_dll.dll
Luego Reinicié WAMP.

En el menú de WAMP, en la parte de extensiones de PHP me figura bajo la sección de 'No extension='
Al clickear encima, se abre una ventana de consola que dice:

> Sorry The 'mi_dll.dll' extension file exists, but there is no
>   'extension=mi_dll.dll' line in php.ini

Esa línea está tanto el php.ini de apache como de php.

Hay forma de solucionar esto?

Adicionalmente, bajo la sección de 'No dll file', aparece también 'mi_dll', y al clickear, se abre una ventana de comando que dice:

> Sorry, The line 'extension=php_mi_dll.dll' exists in php.ini file but
>   there is no php_mi_dll.dll file in ext/ directory.

Comment: Saludos, podrias comentar que dll deseas agregar a WampServer..?

Comment: @DiegoAvila es una dll que me dieron cuya función es desencriptar un string. No conozco el funcionamiento interno de la misma. Con visual studio c# puedo levantarla correctamente, pero como tengo mi desarrollo en php me gustaría poder utilizarla allí.

Comment: Bien, mi sugerencia seria conocer que metodo usa para desencriptar tu dll en C# y esto pasarlo a PHP, porque al parecer da la impresión que no es compatible con PHP ..porque los pasos que mencionas son como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803355/5215609

Comment: en teoria deberia funcionar sin problemas el agregar el dll..!!

Comment: Luego de reiniciar el ordenador, finalmente apareción la dll en la sección de php modules. Ahora, al momento de ejecutarla me aparece: "error: Failed to create COM object `mi_dll.Desencriptar': Sintaxis no v�lida"

Comment: te sugiero revisar el "DLL" desde la terminal de comandos: "regsvr32 mi_dll.dll"

Comment: la dll fue registrada con ese comando, aún así, sigo obteniendo el mismo error